# Appearance для FocusedRow после потери фокуса

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress

Возникла достаточно простая проблема.
У меня есть форма с двумя элементами:
1) chooseBox - форма для выбора из списка;
2) gridView - представление в таблице GridControl.

Я хочу настроить, что бы выделенная строка в GridView меняла свой цвет на желтый:

```
gridView.Appearance.FocusedRow.Options.UseBackColor = true;
gridView.Appearance.FocusedRow.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
```

Дело в том, что при смене фокуса с gridView на chooseBox (или на любой иной элемент) цвет сбрасывается в базовый (непонятно зачем).
Как мне оставить выделение строчки даже если фокус уже на другом контроле?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда грид не сфокусирован, применяется [GridViewAppearance.HideSelectionRow](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridViewAppearances.HideSelectionRow.property). Это можно отключить с помощью опции [GridOptionsSelection.EnableAppearanceHideSelection](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridOptionsSelection.EnableAppearanceHideSelection.property).

Comment: Спасибо! Можете еще подсказать, как сделать, что бы выбранная ячеика то же закрашивалась в другой цвет? А то когда фокус теряется 3 столбца красятся в желтый, а один остается белым.

Comment: @TitovS.P., [GridOptionsSelection.EnableAppearanceFocusedCell](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridOptionsSelection.EnableAppearanceFocusedCell.property).